# C programming : Trying to print the reverse of the products of all the 2-digit numbers

Tags: c

As the title states, I'm trying to print the reverse of the products of all the 2 digit numbers.

For example : for 100,200,300..., I want to print 001,002,003.

Here's my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
    int rev=0,revprod;
    int i,j,prod;
    for(i=10;i<100;i++)
    {
        for(j=10;j<100;j++)
        {
            prod=i*j; 
            revprod=prod;
            while(revprod!=0)
            {
                rev=rev*10;
                rev=rev + (revprod%10);
                revprod=revprod/10; 
            }
            printf("%d\n",rev);
        } 
    }
}
```

It prints garbage values. I can't figure out the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the first number has been processed, `rev` is no longer 0 and since there is no code to clear it, the subsequent inner loops will generate the wrong values.

You need to stick a:

```
rev = 0;
```

before the inner `while` loop. Alternatively, you can move the declaration and put:

```
int rev = 0;
```

before the `while` loop, that's pretty nice since it makes it clearer that this particular variable is only used in the inner scope.

Also, remember that

```
rev = rev * 10;
```

can always be written as

```
rev *= 10;
```

which is much clearer to experienced C programmers (it makes it more obvious that `rev` is being multiplied) and a good habit to pick up.